# Spring Boot Custom Validator Not Found Error: HV000030

Tags: spring-annotations, customvalidator, spring-validator

Total newbie having trouble learning how to modify a spring boot application with a custom validator(maven, h2 repository, thymeleaf, not sure if this info is implied or necessary so here it is). I cannot get my validator to work as intended. It is supposed to check if the inventory of an object is >= the min && <= the max level. I've created an @interface and a validator class and added the annotation to just above the variables in the abstract class that creates the entities, but I am getting an error when I try to use the validator. The error makes me think I'm just not referencing it correctly, or maybe it needs to be added to the Controllers for the classes that extend the abstract class. Anyway, feeling lost, any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated

Error reads: UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'com.example.demo.validators.MinMaxInv'.

Annotation interface

```
package com.example.demo.validators;


import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = MinMaxInvValidator.class)
public @interface MinMaxInv {
    String message() default "Inventory must be between min and max";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

}
```

Validator class

```
public class MinMaxInvValidator implements ConstraintValidator<MinMaxInv, Part> {
    @Override
    public void initialize(MinMaxInv constraintAnnotation) {
        ConstraintValidator.super.initialize(constraintAnnotation);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Part part, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        if(part.getInv() > part.getMax() || part.getInv() < part.getMin()){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Abstract class, getters and setters not shown

```
@Entity
@ValidDeletePart
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="part_type",discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
@Table(name="Parts")
public abstract class Part implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    long id;
    String name;
    double price;
    @MinMaxInv
    int inv;
    int max;
    int min;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="product_part", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="part_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="product_id"))
    Set<Product> products= new HashSet<>();

    public Part() {
    }

    public Part(String name, double price, int inv, int max, int min) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.inv = inv;
        this.max = max;
        this.min = min;
    }

    public Part(long id, String name, double price, int inv, int max, int min) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.inv = inv;
        this.max = max;
        this.min = min;
    }
```

Error

```
2023-08-17 10:46:03.640 ERROR 3260 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'com.example.demo.validators.MinMaxInv' validating type 'java.lang.Integer'. Check configuration for 'inv'] with root cause

javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'com.example.demo.validators.MinMaxInv' validating type 'java.lang.Integer'. Check configuration for 'inv'
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.getExceptionForNullValidator(ConstraintTree.java:116) ~[hibernate-validator-6.2.3.Final.jar:6.2.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.getInitializedConstraintValidator(ConstraintTree.java:162) ~[hibernate-validator-6.2.3.Final.jar:6.2.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.SimpleConstraintTree.validateConstraints(SimpleConstraintTree.java:54) ~[hibernate-validator-6.2.3.Final.jar:6.2.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:75) ~[hibernate-validator-6.2.3.Final.jar:6.2.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.doValidateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:130) ~[hibernate-validator-6.2.3.Final.jar:6.2.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.validateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:123) ~[hibernate-validator-6.2.3.Final.jar:6.2.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateMetaConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:555) ~[hibernate-validator-6.2.3.Final.jar:6.2.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForSingleDefaultGroupElement(ValidatorImpl.java:518) ~[hibernate-validator-6.2.3.Final.jar:6.2.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:488) ~[hibernate-validator-6.2.3.Final.jar:6.2.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:450) ~[hibernate-validator-6.2.3.Final.jar:6.2.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:400) ~[hibernate-validator-6.2.3.Final.jar:6.2.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:172) ~[hibernate-validator-6.2.3.Final.jar:6.2.3.Final]
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter.validate(SpringValidatorAdapter.java:109) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.validation.ValidatorAdapter.validate(ValidatorAdapter.java:66) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.validate(DataBinder.java:900) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.validateIfApplicable(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:382) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:173) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:122) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:179) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:146) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:889) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

Answer (score 0):

From the stacktrace:

> No validator could be found for constraint 'com.example.demo.validators.MinMaxInv' validating type 'java.lang.Integer'

To fix this exception, you should remove the `@MinMaxInv` annotation from the `int inc` field and place it on the class:

```
@MinMaxInv
public abstract class Part implements Serializable {
    // ...
}
```

But I'm not sure it will work the way you expect.

Comment: Oh wow, that worked! However, I am not seeing the message appear when this prevents the inv that is above the max or below the min from being added. Is this what you meant by "not sure it will work the way you expect?" Any tips for getting that message to work? I've tried just adding it to the constraint like @MinMaxInv(message="sample") and also adding to the isValid method: constraintValidatorContext.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
            constraintValidatorContext.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("Inventory must be between min and max").addConstraintViolation();

Comment: @Lalochezia there is a good [article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-custom-validation-message-source) that explains how to work with custom validation messages